# Timings of cURL request by getting details from curl_getinfo()

Tags: php, performance, curl, time

I wrote a little script to diagnose the connection time of my website, and here is the result:

```
Lookup time:                0.6454ms
Connect time:               1.1611ms
Pretransfer time:           1.1615ms
Redirect time:              0ms
Time to 1st Byte time:      43.397ms
Total time:                 43.445ms
```

The code used is as follow:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
if(curl_exec($ch) !== false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo 'Lookup time: ' . "\t\t" . ($info['namelookup_time'] * 1000) . 'ms' . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Connect time: ' . "\t\t" . ($info['connect_time'] * 1000) . 'ms' . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Pretransfer time: ' . "\t" . ($info['pretransfer_time']) . 'ms' . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Redirect time: ' . "\t\t" . ($info['redirect_time'] * 1000) . 'ms' . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Time to 1st Byte time: ' . "\t" . ($info['starttransfer_time'] * 1000) . 'ms' . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Total time: ' . "\t\t" . ($info['total_time'] * 1000) . 'ms' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I don't quite understand the result above.

1. Why does the Time to First Byte (TTFB) time equal to Total Time?
2. Is the above timing cumulative? If yes, the transfer time is equal to 0ms?
3. What does Pretransfer time mean?

Output of `curl_getinfo($ch)`:

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://www.example.com/apply.php
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 302
    [header_size] => 412
    [request_size] => 88
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.043445
    [namelookup_time] => 0.006454
    [connect_time] => 0.011611
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.011615
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.043397
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => http://www.example.com/index.php
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't** round time for any thorough analysis of a request. `0ms` and `0.5ms` are ages apart for computers; read the raw numbers to avoid confusion.

1) If an HTTP request returns a single resource (as opposed to a complete web page), TTFB and Total Time are both the same things, unless the amount of data returned by the server was considerably larger.

2) Yes it is cumulative. Increase the amount of data returned by the URL and you will see that the transfer time will also increase from 0ms

3) Time spent waiting for the server to respond after it accepted the request

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, my site contains images, external CSS and JS & lots of text. Can the cURL info obtain the load time of these too? can this considered as "amount of data was considerably larger" ?

Comment: Since you requested just one resource, even if others were listed on the web page they were not called. All the text/html that was returned to your client at the same time as the first byte was sent. If you make that HTML go longer just for a test, TTFB will start to differ from Total time

Comment: is there any chance cURL can include everything from the site ( CSS, JS, images, etc )? or I have to go for alternative solution, like PhantomJS / CasperJS ?

Comment: It can't itself. You will have to fetch those resources in subsequent calls if you continue to use cURL

Comment: If you edit your question with the complete output of `curl_getinfo()` it might make the answers a little more specific and the discussion more interesting cause without the rounding you will notice differences already; even if negligible

Comment: Added the output, and yes, without the rounding, the numbers make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

> - Why does the Time to First Byte (TTFB) time equal to Total Time?

It depends on total data. If your total data transferred is almost zero then it will be equal.

> - Is the above timing cumulative? If yes, the transfer time is equal to 0ms?

Yes, it is cumulative. If data is big then it would have increased.

> - What does Pretransfer time mean?

Pretransfer time means time in seconds from start until just before file transfer begins

For more info on [Curl GetInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

It also depends on your connection speed.

You should also check this values.

1. CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD - Total number of bytes uploaded
2. CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD - Total number of bytes downloaded
3. CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD - Average download speed
4. CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD - Average upload speed

So you will understand your speed and data size.

**Update:**

With your updated output, we can clearly understand there is almost no data is uploaded and downloaded. So timings are making more sense now.

Comment: But the total data has at least 1KB, which can probably unable to finish transfer in 0ms (total time - TTFB)

Comment: @Raptor: Check updated answer and update your question with updated data